# How can I find the number of words in a given string?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, turbo-pascal

I'm trying to find the number of words in a given string in Pascal?

This is my starter coede:

```
Program P1;
 var s:string;
     i,k:integer;
 begin
   write('Enter a string:  '); readln(s);
   k:=0;
   for i:=1 to length(s) do
    begin
        if(s[i] = ' ') then k:=k+1;
    end;
    write('Number of words ', k);
end.
```

Comment: How does this fail? Have you tried to "desk check" your code, by pretending to be a dumb computer and executing each step of your program the way a computer would?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin the thing, the program only counts if a space character is found for example if i have the string "I have 4 apples" the total counted words would be 3 because there are only 3 spaces

Comment: Then perhaps what you need to do is (a) refine how you define a word, and (b) figure out what you can do to account for a word that doesn't end with a space. The two problems are actually pretty closely linked.

Comment: You might find [Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) and [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661938/freepascal-regexp-replace) to be useful.

Comment: Did you see https://www.rejbrand.se/rejbrand/article.asp?ItemIndex=505?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I will take a close look at it.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count all the words in a textfile with multiple space characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877404/how-to-count-all-the-words-in-a-textfile-with-multiple-space-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Free Pascal there is a [wordcount](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/strutils/wordcount.html) function in the strutils unit:

```
uses strutils;
var s : string;
begin 
  write('Enter a string:  '); readln(s);
  writeln('Number of words: ',wordcount(s,[' ','.',',']));
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You may implement the program as [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) with two states ("inside word" and "word separator"):

```
Program P1;
 type TState = (INSIDE_WORD, WORD_SEPARATOR);
 var s:string;
     i,k:integer;
     state: TState;
 begin
   write('Enter a string:  '); readln(s);
   k:=0;
   state := WORD_SEPARATOR;
   for i:=1 to length(s) do
    begin
        case state of
        INSIDE_WORD:
          begin
            if (s[i] = ' ') then state := WORD_SEPARATOR;
          end;
        WORD_SEPARATOR:
          begin
            if (s[i] <> ' ') then begin
              k:=k+1;
              state := INSIDE_WORD;
            end;
          end;
        end;
    end;
    write('Number of words ', k);
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which treats every non-letter as a word separator:

```
PROGRAM P1;

    VAR
        wordCount: Integer;
        insideWord, letterRead: Boolean;
        ch: Char;

BEGIN
    wordCount := 0;
    insideWord := FALSE;
    Write('Enter a string:  ');
    Read(ch);
    WHILE NOT EoLn DO BEGIN
        letterRead := (ch >= 'A') AND (ch <= 'Z') OR (ch >= 'a') AND (ch <= 'z');
        IF NOT insideWord AND letterRead THEN
            Inc(wordCount);
        insideWord := letterRead;
        Read(ch)
    END;
    WriteLn('Number of words: ', wordCount)
END.
```